# What is the best way to use the option 'Merge [branch name] into current branch' - SourceTree

Tags: merge, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to know what is the best way to use the command: `Merge branch name into current branch`

[image: options image]

**What i am doing** (Let us suppose I want to merge `master` into `develop`):

1. I checkout to the `master` branch and pull all the recent changes.
2. Then I go back to the `develop` branch.
3. I right click on the `master` branch and click `Merge branch name into current branch`.
4. And the `master` branch will merge into the `develop` branch.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methodology looks correct.

If you are not seeing any changes tothe branch you are merging into - then it is likely [this branch is already up-to-date with the branch merged into it](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/How-context-menu-option-quot-Merge-branch-into-current-branch/qaq-p/400814).

You can also look up the following references on the Merge comnmand you are using:

- [Git Tutorial (Beginner): Using GitLab & Source Tree](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=4F3uBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=sourcetree%20%22Merge%20branch%20name%20into%20current%20branch%22&source=bl&ots=nZCrq3WrCf&sig=6K1zHlWkIy7wDSgqMMVQHef7mjU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI1Lu-tfvaAhWQyaQKHZAjBfAQ6AEIMzAC)

Comment: I already merge through this way. I just want to confirm it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks you @AbdulRauf : If this answer was helpful to you, please consider selecting it as your questions answer. Take care buddy.